# Java Apache poi cannot delete folder containing Excel files and cannot delete sheets in Excel files

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to write a program with apache poi in Java that should edit some Excel files.

I am running into the following problem: the folder which contains my Excel file seems to have been locked after having run the program. If I try to delete it, it says I need to get permission from the administrator. I do not get this message with any other folders in the same location, nor with folders inside this folder. I am the administrator on this computer, as it is my private laptop.

The second problem I have is that after I run the program, I am thereafter unable to delete sheets that it created. I have to manually save the Excel file, close it, reopen it, and then I can delete sheets again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your operating system? How did you try to remove it? (via Java code or directly from operating system's file explorer?) I am not sure, but I guess you are on a windows machine, and you run your java code in an administrator mode but your current logged-in user is not privileged.

Comment: I am on Windows 10, trying to remove it from file explorer. How do I make my current logged-in user privileged?

Comment: To change your user account-type check this link https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-user-account-type-windows-10

Comment: Technically, working with an excel file does not required an administrator privileges, does require?  How do you run you Java application? With an IDE? (if yes, do not run your IDE as an admin) With a command through CMD or Terminal? (if yes, do not run the CMD as an admin). Do not forget that a  Java application does NOT directly have an administrator access, and of course there is not need to has unless under some circumstances you need.

Comment: I just went through all the steps mentioned in the article, but it seems the account I'm working on is already an administrator everywhere. It also looks like I'm not running Eclipse (the IDE I'm using) as an administrator.

Comment: It's strange, I am not a windows expert, but it would be useful if you share your CODE. (especially the writing section). Do you have `new File()` in your code and did you manipulate its reference? Sending more comments seems to be as a chat-room...

Comment: I created one method that allows me to retrieve a files path or filename from files in a specific folder. This is the code:
`ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
  File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\damar\\OneDrive\\Documenten\\FolderTest\\Folderretouren\\Niet verdeeld");
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();`

The method then returns the Arraylist of either names of the files or paths of the files. Could this be where the problem lies?

Comment: No, there are some methods like `file.setWritable()`, but it seems that you did not use them. If the problem is related to your code, we need to see your code especially the writing section. On your windows do this: `Right click on the folder -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> Add -> Everyone`; I've got no more suggestions I hope it helps you.

Comment: So I found a solution: I deleted all the contents of the folder. Then I was able to delete the folder itself. I discovered this on accident, because I was playing around with File.delete(), which said that you can only delete a directory if it is empty. Thank you for helping out. There are too many places in my code where I write something, so to show you all that would probably not be worthwile. This solution will have to suffice. 

The second problem is not yet fixed though. Can I add you privately somewhere so we can talk?